# How does php_value auto_prepend_file in apache work with php does it always stay in memory?

Tags: php, file-io, apache, httpd.conf

I am wondering how autoprepend works with php and httpd.

Does it load the file once or does it load it every time a script is called by apache?

If I have a file that reads files from the disk and loads them with auto_prepend do they stay in memory or does it get loaded with every call.

I am trying to have a file load and stay in memory and only be reloaded once apache is restarted.

```
    <Directory> 
            php_value auto_prepend_file /path/to/file
     </Directory>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`auto_prepend_file` causes the named file to be parsed before any other script is parsed; think of `auto_prepend_file` as a `require` statement that exists at the top of every other script you have (except it doesn't).

Comment: So its not stored in memory its just always loaded first no mater what?